# Black Screen on Boot HP Pavilion 20 Desktop

Tags: boot, hp, radeon

I am new to Linux/Ubuntu.  I have a HP Pavilion 20 Desktop and have just installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 from a flash drive.

Processor: AMD E1-1200 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics x 2, Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.8, 128 bits)

The screen goes black when I boot up.  I am able to get it working by going to the GRUB menu and typing "nomodeset" I tried updating my graphics card driver but no update was available.  Could use some help.

Answer (score -1):

This answer from Coldfish fixed the problem.

You should add this option to /etc/default/grub, firstly:

sudo nano /etc/default/grub

and then add nomodeset to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT:

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

And then save by hitting Ctrl+O, then exit nano with Ctrl+X, then simply run:

sudo update-grub

Comment: Adding `nomodeset` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` allows the Ubuntu GUI to boot on-screen, but the graphics options are extremely limited (only 800x600 is available as a resolution). When booting without `nomodeset`, if I hit CTRL+ALT+F1 during boot, something occurs and Ubuntu boots normally, and the resolution is correctly set at a 16:9 resolution. Any ideas why?